# Ways to enhance a trial user's first time experience

Tags: user-interface, workflow, user-experience

I am looking for some ideas on enhancing a trial-user's user experience when he uses a product for the first time. The product is aimed at a particular domain and has various features/workflows. Experienced users of the product naturally find interesting ways to combine features to get the results they want (somewhat like using an IDE from a programmer's perspective).Trial users get to use all features of the product in a limited fashion (For ex: If there is a search functionality, the trial-user might see only the top 20 results, or he may be allowed to search only a 100 times). My question is: What are the best ways to help a trial-user explore/understand the possibilities of the product in the trial period, especially in the first 20 - 60 mins before the user gives up on the product?

Edit 1: The product is a desktop app (served via JNLP, so no install required) and as pointed out in the comments, the expectations can be different in this case. That said, many webapps do take a virtual desktop form and so, all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It's not my application, but I think this app: http://universesandbox.com/ does a great job of showing what is capable in it with it's trial system. (And is, indeed, an amazing application).

Comment: Is this an online application or desktop?  I ask because desktop apps have a bigger barrier to entry.  And the nature of the trial may be influenced by this barrier.

Comment: steve ... thx for that question. It's a desktop app and you are correct about the varying nature of trial users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can, avoid feature limiting a trial. it stops the user from experiencing what the product is ACTUALLY like. It also prevents a user from finding out if a feature actually works like they want/expect/need it to.

if you have a trial version, and you can, optimise it for first time use. focus on / highlight the features that allow the user to quickly and easily get benefits for useful output from the system.

allow users to export any data they enter into a trial system - and indicate that this is possible/easy. you don't want them to be put off from trying something because of a potential for wasted effort.

avoid users being required to do lots of configuration before using a trial. prepopulate settings based on typical/common/popular settings. you may also want to consider having default settings for different types of usage. e.g. "If you want to see what the system is like for scenario X, use configuration J. If you want to see what the system is like for use case Y, use configuration K." where J & K are collections of settings best suited to a particular type of usage.

Comment: +1 for "allow users to export any data they enter into a trial system". I can see how that would frustrate the user if it was not allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Check out how blinksale.com handles this.  It's an invoicing app, but to prevent it from looking too empty for a new account, they show static images in places where you'd actually have content if you used the app.  Makes it look less barren at first until you get your own data in.

Answer (score 3):

I'll speak from personal experience while evaluating trial applications.

The most annoying trial applications are those which keep popping up nag screens or constantly reminding me that I'm using a trial. Trials which act exactly like the real product from the beginning till the end of the trial period are just awesome. Limited features are annoying, the only exception I can think of when you could use it is where you have **rarely** used feature which would allow people to exploit the trial (by using this "once-in-lifetime" needed feature and uninstalling). If you have for example video editing software trial which puts "trial" watermark on output, I'd uninstall it as soon as I'd notice it. In my opinion trial should seamlessly integrate into user work-flow so that once the trial ends they would think "Hey, I have been using this awesome program almost each day since I got the trial, I absolutely have to buy it." Sure some people will exploit it, but at the end you should target the group which will use your product in daily work-flow instead of one time users. Even if user "trials" it 2 times per year, he will keep coming back to your product and might even buy it after 2nd or 3rd "one-time use".

(Sorry for the wall of the text and rant)

As for how to improve the first session. I usually find my way around programs easily, but one time only pop-up/screen (or with check-box to never show it again) with videos showing off best features and intended work-flow are quite helpful. Also links to sample documents might be helpful. If your application can self-present itself (for example slide-show about the your slide-show program) you could include such document. People don't like to read long and boring help files, but if you have designer in your team, you could ask him to make a short colourful intro pdf. Also don't throw all the features at the user at the same time. Split information into simple categories and if user is interested into one specific category keep feeding him more specific information. That's why videos are so good, with 3-6 x ~3-5 minute videos you can tell a lot. Also depending how complex your program is you could include picture with information where specific things are located on the screen.

Just my personal opinion, I have never made a trial myself. Hope it helps.

Comment: Despite not having made a trial, your ideas indicate you have given it a fair amout of thought. Wish I could accept 2 answers, because there are some interesting points here.

Answer (score 2):

An interactive walk through/lab exercise that really highlights the major and exciting offerings of your application.

Example: Yahoo mail does the same when the users opt to use new mail interface

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways you can go with this.  I still can't claim to have found the best approach.

However, my plan from the beginning with my online (Silverlight) software was to give away something thousands of people will find useful and can use for free.  The free version is pretty well representative of the professional product, with only a few features missing that enhance productivity (I'm working on those professional features now).  And then I do have a nag popup that comes up every 5 minutes suggesting that you should buy it. That popup can be dismissed as many times as you want.  I know that popup will annoy some people but I suppose that's the trade off.  There is no perfect plan.  But I don't think the occasional nag popup scares *that* many people away, especially when it can be dismissed with a single click.

I was inspired by [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/), which has been hugely successful over the past couple years.  My trial/nag popup way of doing things was copied almost exactly from Balsamiq.  I honestly don't know if this is the ideal plan, but it has obviously worked for them.  By the way, I think another reason for Balsamiq's success is that the demo doesn't have to be downloaded & installed.  Since the demo is in Flash, there's a very high conversion rate of users actually trying it and becoming addicted to it.

Comment: I like your answer, but it actually refers more about how to handle trial-users over the course of the trial. I am interested in the first 1-hour or so when their interest can be captured.

Comment: People most likely doesn't spend more then 10minutes in regex helper programs, so the nag screen probably doesn't even show up or only shows once or twice. I wouldn't consider it annoying because it's not "main priority" application, but imagine trying coding in IDE which has 5 min nag screen. Argh! But it's a good point - a lot depends on application type.

Comment: Sorry I guess I went on a bit of a tangent there.  And I don't know how much of it applies to your scenario.  Because honestly I don't think I would use the same approach with a desktop app.